# Firebase Invite does not send invites after update

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-invites

I am working on the debug version of an android app. I was able to send both SMS and email invites until I recently installed a different OS on my machine (both Linux). As a result, I also updated Android Studio to the latest version, and imported my old project settings. The rest of the application works fine, I can also start the activity for selecting invites, it displays the message that `Invitation was sent`, but `AppInviteInvitation.getInvitationIds` returns 0 length array in `onActivityResult`.

I tried to add Sha1 and Sha256 to the app in the Firebase console, removed Firebase completely and then added it back to the android project in Android Studio (also removed and added again application and project in the firebase console). So checked and tried most of the solutions on SO, but none seems to work. I am probably omitting something. I am using two google accounts, one for firebase, one for email sending from device.

What else could I verify? Is there any way to dig deeper in Firebase invites in order to find the issue?

The intent:

```
private void onInviteClicked() {
  Intent intent = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder("MyApp")
        .setMessage("Some message of 90 nospecial chars")
//      .setDeepLink(createDynamicLink(2))
        .setCustomImage(Uri.parse("http://correct url"))
        .setCallToActionText("Call to action")
        .build();
  startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_INVITE);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short: keep message short (tested with < 40 chars)

Long: My intent actually contained a 90 character message (no special chars), which was sent just fine before the update. After the update, I need to reduce the length of the message (tested with ~40 characters, none is special), in order for it to be sent.

I wonder what determined this behavior. Things that were changed: java (previously was oracle jdk, now it is the java that comes by default with Android Studio); Maybe also java version. Build tools version 25.0.2 -> 26.0.0.